# shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method never called

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, appdelegate

I'm creating an app which has a webview. When user click to a link or a button in the webview, I want to be able to get the new url, and edit the new url.

shouldStartLoadWithRequest should do the trick, but that method is never called when I click to a link. I cannot find why this doesn't work.

I have read somewhere that I need to add this line :

```
webView.delegate = (id)self;
```

I tried it, and still get the same issue. Please help

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *currentURL = [[request URL] absoluteString] ;

    NSLog(@"Url: %@", currentURL);
    return YES;
}
```

Controller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView.delegate = (id)self;
    NSString *tokenString = @"123";
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *fullURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.69:8888/webapp/test.php?uid=%@", tokenString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Controller` instance adds itself as the delegate then the method you add to the `AppDelegate` instance will never be called.

Move the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method into your `Controller` class.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your view controller as the web view's delegate. But then you've implemented the UIWebView delegate method  in our application's delegate instead.

Try implementing that delegate method in your view controller. Your view controller is your web view's delegate.